# Node.js TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

**index.js**

```
const o = require('./altoken')

    for(const i=1; i<99; i++){
        
        if(o.opts[i].identity.username === null){break;}; //error here
        
        message.guild.channels.create(o.opts[i].identity.username, {type: "text",parent: id})
    }
```

**altoken.js**

```
 module.exports.opts1 = {
  mro: {
    as: false,
  },
  identity: {
    username: "x",
    password: "x"
  },
  krlo: [
    'x',
  ]
};
```

I want to create as many channels as modules in altoken.js but I am getting an error.
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Comment: `module.exports` doesn't contain a property `opts`. `o.opts` returns `undefined`. `o.opts[1]` is an error.

Comment: how can i fix ?

Comment: o.opts1.identity.username, o.opts2.identity.username, o.opts3.identity.username how can i use

Comment: This is also useful: [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Comment: how to use in o.opts.`${i}`.identity.username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to access a property by dynamic property name. You need bracket notation:

```
o['opts' + i]
```

Example:

```
const o = require('./altoken')

for(const i=1; i<99; i++){
    
    if(o['opts' + i].identity.username === null){break;}; //error here
    
    message.guild.channels.create(o['opts' + i].identity.username, {type: "text",parent: id})
}
```